# Angle - Bootstrap Admin App + AngularJS not working in IIS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, iis

We were about to start a new website in the Angle Bootstrap Admin theme, but it would not work when hosted in IIS. It only shows a blank index.html page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this theme used some features which are in most of the cases not supported on a default IIS webserver. [Get the theme here](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/angle-bootstrap-admin-app-angularjs-WB04HF123)

1. JSON : you have to enable JSON support on your IIS webserver or in your web.config file, see link [JSON IN IIS 7](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.VHgyRzGG8SQ)
2. ASP: to handle JSON file, classic ASP must be enabled on your ASP webserver, see link [Enable ASP in IIS](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-install-iis7-on-windows-7.aspx)
3. JSON Handler: link JSON mimetype to classic ASP Handler (2nd part of the first link)
4. PHP is needed: PHP can be installed by using the "Web Platform Installer" from Microsoft
5. WOFF fonts: add this mimetype to your IIS (extension = .woff , mimetype = application/x-woff
6. MD : the documentation uses MD files, you need to add this mimetype to your webserver [Link to howto](http://getkirby.com/forum/panel/20130228/markdown-mime-type/), but in short (extension = .md , mimetype = text/x-markdown), can also be done in your web.config file

If your are able to follow these steps, you will get a nice looking dashboard[image: dashboard]

And this is how the documentation should look now [image: Documentation]

If some features are still not working, just contact me :-)